# Did Signal get renamed or removed from Elm v0.17?

Tags: signals, elm, elm-signal

I am following the tutorial of http://www.elm-tutorial.org/020_signals/introduction.html elm.

When I tried to execute the Signals example. I got the following error.

```
Exception : 

Cannot find variable `Signal.map`.

12|   Signal.map view Mouse.x
  ^^^^^^^^^^
The qualifier `Signal` is not in scope.
```

I am using Elm : 0.17 and core 4.0.0

I could not find Signal module in the core package

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, Signal was removed along with a number of other things (Mailboxes, Addresses, etc.) in favor of a move towards subscriptions ([`Sub`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.0/Platform-Sub#Sub)) and commands ([`Cmd`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.0/Platform-Cmd#Cmd)), rendering much of the documentation out there obsolete. See the 0.17 announcement for more information: http://elm-lang.org/blog/farewell-to-frp

You can find the upgrade plan here: https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.17.md